# Does every git branch of an NPM project have different node_modules dependencies?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I assume that when developing an `NPM` project, that every `git` branch (or whatever version control system you use) probably points to a different set of `node_modules` on the filesystem. Is that true? How does that work? Does it pose any problems for diskspace etc?

Or perhaps, since `node_modules` is most commonly `.gitignore'd`, then the `node_modules` files are shared between Git branches? Again, how would/does that work?

*Note that Node.js / NPM is fundamentally different than other platforms/languages since dependencies are typically stored locally to a proejct rather than in some central location on a machine.

Comment: No. There's probably a way to do that, but I add `node_modules` to `.gitignore` and because only one branch is checked out at a time in the same directory, then they all use the same modules.

Comment: that doesn't make sense - what if one branch has entirely different dependencies or versions than the other branch. I don't think gitignore solves that...

Comment: If a branch has totally different dependencies than another, then it just might be a different project, and perhaps belongs in its own repo. Do you ever intend to merge these branches back together? That being said, you can totally commit different `node_modules` to diverged branches, but disk would get eaten quickly especially because git doesn't store deltas, but snapshots of the whole repository. You'd probably be better off committing the different `package.json` files and running a git hook that would re-install the dependencies on branch checkout.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By convention, one **should not** add any files, libraries or binaries which can be generated or pulled in from an external source.  This includes things like `node_modules`; since that is made readily available* once you do `npm install`, there's no reason or incentive** to want to put that into your source control.  At worst, it will also bloat your repository, filling your diffs with things you simply don't control and don't necessarily want to review.

I would not expect different Git branches of an NPM project to contain different `node_modules` folders.  I'd only expect the one `node_modules` folder, and if a branch gave me fits about dependencies, I'd look to reinstall the dependencies (and note it down to be sure that something *else* hadn't gone awry).

As an addendum, any files or folders in `.gitignore` are simply not indexed or tracked by Git.  If the contents of those files or folders change, Git is none the wiser.  This also means, when switching between branches, the contents of the files or folders in `.gitignore` remain the same.

<sup>*: Provided that the library you're using isn't suddenly yanked.  Or the repository is not impacted by a colossal DDoS.</sup>

<sup>**: There *may* be some incentive to do this given that the reliability of certain NPM packages hasn't been 100% this year, but that's a team and architecture-driven decision, and I doubt that placing it into source control is the most ideal and convenient way to deal with it.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

There are two schools of thought, and both have merit.

> 1) Never check in `node_modules` and rebuild on deploy/install

The approach relies heavily on NPM and the connectivity of your deploy environment. `node_modules` are downloaded and installed (and/or compiled) each time the deploy is run.

**Positives:**
Your repository is much smaller.

NPM modules are installed in the environment they will run on.

**Concerns:**
Tied to 3rd party for sources - Go read about that whole `left-pad` thing. If one dependency cannot be downloaded, your entire build system is hung out to dry. "Cranky and paranoid old timers" will cite this as *the* reason to check everything in (or run your own private NPM somewhere).

Branch management - Like you mentioned in the question, some branches might not have the same dependencies. Dev1 adds a new features and used a new package. Now Dev2 runs the `dev` branch or whatever, and everything is broken and they need to know to `npm install` the new package. More subtle is the case where a npm package is version changed (now you need `npm update` as `npm install` will say nothing has changed), or where their `node_modules` are upgraded to work on "new feature 10" but they need to clear everything out to "downgrade" to go fix "prior bug 43". If you are in active development with a team of more than 2-3, watch out for this one.

Build Time - If it is a concern, it takes a little longer to download and install everything. Or a *lot* longer.

> 2) Always check in everything you can

This approach includes `node_modules` as part of the repo.

**Positives:**
Not dependent on 3rd party sources. You have what you need to run. You code can live on its own forever, and it does not matter if npm is down or a repo is deleted.

Branches are independent, so new features from Dev1 are auto included when Dev2 switches to that branch

Deploy time is shorter because not much needs to be installed.

**Concerns:**
Repository is much larger. Clones of code take longer as there are many more files.

Pull Requests need extra care. If a package is updated (or installed) along with core code, the PR is a mess and sometimes unintelligible. "500 files changed", but really you updated a package and changed two lines of core code. It can help to break down into two PRs - one that is is a mess (the package update) and one that is actually reviewable (the core code change). Again, be prepared for this one. The packages will not change too often, but your code review takes a little longer (or a little more care) when they do.

OS Dependent Packages can break. Basically anything that is installed/compiled with `gyp` can be OS dependent (among others). Most packages are "pure JS" and, being just scripts, run everywhere. Imagine all your devs run and test on OSX while you deploy to Linux, you *cannot* check in those packages that were compiled on a MAC because they will not run on Linux. An odd workaround for this is to define most packages as "dev dependencies" (`--save-dev`) and the ones that need compiled as normal ("production", `--save`), then you run `npm install --production` so the dev dependencies are not installed (and are already present), but the others are.

> Conclusions

It depends. (Don't you hate hearing that all the time? : )

Depending on your team and your concerns, you might go either approach. Both have their merits, and you will decide which is more beneficial to you. Both have drawbacks as well, so be aware of those *before* you get bit!

Answer (score 5):

Personally I ignore .node_modules but I have different package.json in different branch and when I switch I reinstall the dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Two branches having different set of node modules is in scenario where one branch is in development phase and other is your production branch. In such cases development branch will have more node modules than production. If I am not wrong any other scenario might get you in trouble.

Pushing **node_modules** to remote version control repository is bad practice hence just rely on **npm install** whenever you clone a branch or pull the code to download any new node module added to package.json.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, since you don't have your node_modules in your actual repository, you need to install node modules again and each branch might have its own requirement, as you might update your server.js with new dependency and you also need to make sure you have these newly added node dependencies in your production server as well.